# What foot switch works on a Fender Princeton Chorus s/n M464654?

Tags: electric-guitar

Model PR82 purchased at a rummage sale. Pots and front-panel switches are dirty/inoperative.

Thank you!

Comment: Here's not an appropriate place to ask questions such as this. But a Google about Fender should help.